# Intersection of multi-polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection

How can I get the intersection of 3 multi-polygons in PostGIS?
I have three geometry collection and I want a fourth as the result of intersection of the other three.

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON(((-49.64435197 -29.23896786187647,-49.68688498 -29.290587315131337, etc etc)))

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON(((-38.7333 -15.635996265940811,-38.706199999999995 -15.699596252308577,-38.6708 -15.749496241625828,-38.650999999999996 -15.790396232878372,etc)))

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON(((-38.7333 -15.635996265940811,-38.706199999999995 -15.699596252308577,etc)))

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON(((result)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
ST_GeomFromText(
'MULTIPOLYGON(((-77 56,-52 18,-88 -27,-10 -13,-11 38,-77 56)))'),
ST_GeomFromText(
'MULTIPOLYGON(((-49 63,-32 24,-39 -7,-66 -19,-72 -9,-74 31,-49 63)))')));
```

Comment: Will you please mark the answer as accepted? That will help keep the site's Q&A complete, and future readers will quickly know which answer worked best (in case other answers are added later). Thanks.