# Line intersection with multiple polygons from a shapefile in PostGIS/PostgreSQL database

Tags: shapefile, polygon, line, geometry, intersection

I am trying find where a line (chosen by a user) intersects any of the multiple polygons within the shapefile. The shapefile is in EPSG:4326 and the coordinates are in (longitude, latitude).

I have loaded a shapefile containing all the buildings (i.e. polygons) from the centre of Rome and have built a schema inside a database with a PostGIS extension (note, PostGIS version: 2.3).

Link to SQL dump and shapefiles used for polygons of my current database set up: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/khszbfwg4lw8l64/AABtnTfgld6EyLwTHwR84ICLa?dl=0

output from my current query '':`SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection('LINESTRING (12.497626 41.897156, 12.4922 41.8902)'::geometry, geom::geometry));`

[image: output from terminal]

I realise I am most certainly at fault here, as I'm no PostGIS expert. However, I'm stuck as 'geom'  is a column in the schema, hence, I'm uncertain as to how to proceed.

I have looked at the following similar-ish questions:
[Intersection of multi-polygons in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72491/intersection-of-multi-polygons-in-postgis)
and
[Intersection between line & polygon in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160142/intersection-between-line-polygon-in-postgis)
yet, I am still at loss on how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You'd probably be well served by reading a primer on spatial types and functions. `ST_Intersection` is the wrong function for your purpose. You want `ST_Intersects` in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the table name in a `FROM` clause.

Also, you don't need to cast the `geom` column to `geometry` (it is already a geometry!) and you want to get a result only for intersecting geometries.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_Intersection(
          ST_SetSRID('LINESTRING (12.497626 41.897156, 12.4922 41.8902)'::geometry,4326), 
          geom))
FROM shp_rome_travelo
WHERE ST_Intersects(
         ST_SetSRID('LINESTRING (12.497626 41.897156, 12.4922 41.8902)'::geometry,4326), 
         geom)
```

Comment: Thanks @JGH this is certainly a step in the right direction, running the query however produces an error: "Operation on mixed SRID geometries". I checked and the geometry is definitely correct, geom column has type: geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326). Regardless, I switched the longs-lats order, and got '0 rows' as the result. Which can't be right, see image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cie3mvbfa0ewqd2/LoS_model_0.png?dl=0

Comment: @Gitche see edited answer to set the coordinate system